# How do I say: "I thought everyone liked AKB48"

Tags: translation

I was talking to a friend and he said he didn't like AKB48! I'm shocked, because AKB48 is so popular in Japan! How do I say: "I thought everyone liked AKB48"? Maybe something like...

> 誰もがAKB48が好きとおもった！

And maybe something extra like "Since they have a café and anime dedicated to them, I thought they would be more popular."

Comment: Don't forget to add のに〜〜！ to the end!

Comment: 「AKB48って、みんな好きだと思ってた！」とか。

Comment: Justin Bieber is extremely popular, therefore everyone likes Justin Bieber? ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would say:

> 「AKB48って、みんな(or誰でも)好きだと思ってた！AKBのカフェとかアニメとかもあるし、もっと人気があると思ってたよ。」

Comment: It's "I thought they would be..." not "I thought they were..." So should it be もっと人気が"出る"と思った? (う～ん・・・ちょっと変な日本語・・・)